# How to run spree commerce under a domain?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, spree, commerce

I have a `vds server` `centos` and `directadmin` installed.

I want to install [spree commerce](http://spreecommerce.com/) and followed the instructions [here](http://guides.spreecommerce.com/developer/getting_started_tutorial.html)

Actually I have installed everything without problem (even spree commerce), but I don't know how to run the website under a domain name.

I have tried installing the script in the `/home/myusername/domains/mydomainname.com/public_html` folder but no luck. I can't access the website under `mydomain.com`

Thanks for your answers...

Answer (score 0):

Not sure I understand what you mean by domain in this context.

If you've installed everything correctly you should be able to run `rails server` to start your *webserver*

and in a browser navigate to `localhost:3000`

to be able to navigate to your own domain you should set

```
Rails.application.routes.default_url_options[:host]= 'mydomainname.com'
```

in `config/environments/development.rb` file

and in your `/etc/hosts` file

```
127.0.0.1       localhost
127.0.0.1       mydomainname.com
```